# Can anyone please explain the meaning of this in XML?

Tags: javascript, xml, blogger

```
<b:if cond='data:view.isLayoutMode'>
<b:template-skin>
<![CDATA[
/**/
]]>
</b:template-skin>
</b:if>
```

I just want to know two things : -

1. what is `<b:if cond='data:view.isLayoutMode'>...</b:if>`
2. What is the difference between `<b:skin>...</b:skin>` and `<b:template-skin>...</b:template-skin>`

I even googled it. But didn't find my answer. It would be of great help if you explain me about these.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have the DTD? That should help explain it. What is the platform? Do they not have documentation for this?

Comment: This is on blogger.

Comment: Where did you get this xml from?

Comment: from a xml blogger template

Comment: Where did you get that from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`b:if` is the Blogger conditional operator, for example if I want to show something only on homepage I will use it like this

```xml
<b:if cond='data:view.isHomepage'>
  <!--show this only on homepage-->
</b:if>
```

you can find more info in [Blogger Help](https://support.google.com/blogger/answer/46995?hl=en)

`<b:if cond='data:view.isLayoutMode'>...</b:if>` is used to show something only on "Layout" tab in the dashboard

`b:skin` to set styles to the entire blog

`b:template-skin` to set syles to blog "Layout" tab only